# Execute Powershell Command remotely and print the output using wmi python

Tags: python, wmi

I want to execute powershell command remotely and fetch the output.
The command is "(New-Object -c Microsoft.Update.Session).CreateUpdateSearcher().Search("IsInstalled=0").Updates|Select Title".
I have tried

```
import wmi
try:
  connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)
  print("connection is established")
  connection.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine='powershell.exe /c (New-Object -c Microsoft.Update.Session).CreateUpdateSearcher().Search("IsInstalled=0").Updates|Select Title  > C:\output.txt')
except:
  print("connection failed")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of the escape characters. Try this:

```
import wmi
try:
  connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)
  print("connection is established")
  connection.Win32_Process.Create (CommandLine=" powershell.exe -command \" & {New-Object -c Microsoft.Update.Session).CreateUpdateSearcher(). Search(\"IsInstalled=0\").Updates|Select Title}\"  > C:\output.txt")
except:
  print("connection failed")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.